# Finding a position with same number in row and column

Tags: algorithm

Given a 2 dimensional array of equal dimensions (i.e. n x n) containing only 0 and 1, how can I find (ignoring matrix[i][i]) the i-th row that has all 0's and the i-th column that has all 1's. If no such i exists then return -1.

**matrix[i][i] can have anything.**

**The expected time complexity is O(n)**

For example

for the given 4 x 4 matrix

```
1 1 0 0
0 1 0 0
1 1 0 1
0 1 0 0
```

the answer is 1 (i is zero based), because 2nd row has all 0's and the 2nd column has all 1's (the value at [1, 1] is ignored).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all such matrix will have only 1 or 0 answers.

1. Start walking by first row till not found 1 (diagonal values
   should be ignored).
2. Start walking by column till not found a 0. If you reach diagonal go to step 1.
3. Repeat 1 till not go out of matrix.

For example you go out in row or column with index i, you should verify that i it is a answer or not. Answer will be i or -1.

As each action handle 1 row or 1 column total amount of actions will be n+n, to verify answer required walk by 1 row and column it will consume n+n actions totally we have 4*n actions this is a **O(n)** complexity.

Example of walking:

```
0 0 0 1 S S S S S S
S S S 1 S S S S S S
S S S 0 0 0 1 S S S
S S S S S S 1 S S S
S S S S S S 1 S S S
S S S S S S 1 S S S
S S S S S S 1 0 0 0 X
S S S S S S S S S S
S S S S S S S S S S
S S S S S S S S S S
```

You should verify answer for 7.

Comment: Your step 3 creates a loop and you proved the inner code is `O(n)`. So the whole complexity is **not** `O(n)` unless you can prove you will execute step 3 a constant number of times

Comment: @fjardon: Walking the columns is unnecessary, since you already know those candidates have been eliminated. Scan left to right, skip to the diagonal if you see a 1. When you reach to right-hand edge, verify that row/column. The scan is clearly O(n) since only one element is checked in each column.

Comment: @rici Please write this as an answer, your algorithm is different and not clear.

Comment: Nice greedy algo! For those who can't understand this is O(n) - think as follows: you are starting from left-top corner, and on each step move either right or down. It is clear that max number of steps will be N+N.

Comment: @SergeyS: Indeed. And, as I said, it can be reduced to N because you don't need to do the down steps. You just jump directly to the diagonal (and don't bother looking at it because diagonals are irrelevant).

Answer (score 0):

Let's get some theory in:

If an all-ones column (ignoring diagonal) exists, then there can be at most 1 row that's all-zeros.

Conversely, if all-zero row exists, there can be at most one all-ones column.

This makes the problem basically linear.

Answer (score -3):

The solution is:

```
return -1
```

Because if some row has all zeroes, and some column has all all ones, what's going to be in the cell where they intersect?

Comment: Please read the problem statement and the given example carefully

Comment: @suyash The problem statement clearly says "ith column ALL 1" and "ith row ALL 0", this means that one value would, by necessity, be both 1 and 0. The problem then transmogrifies into "actually, m[i][i] is irrelevant".

Comment: Ha, well not you've added "ignoring diagonal", it wasn't there before!